# AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageQt' has no attribute 'ImageQt'

Tags: python, image, pyqt4, python-3.7, opencv

```
import sys
import pickle as p
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import numpy as n
import PIL.ImageQt as PQ
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import os

self.currentFrame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
self.currentSeg=Image.fromarray(thresh).convert('RGB')
self.currentSeg = PQ.ImageQt(self.currentSeg)
height,width=self.currentFrame.shape[:2]
```

im getting above error that imageQt has no attribute. ive tried changing `from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt` but it gives `ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageQt' from 'PIL.ImageQt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageQt' from 'PIL.ImageQt'` can be quite misleading.

If you look at the [ImageQt.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/ImageQt.py#L194) source code, you'll see that the `ImageQt` class is only defined if it successfully detects one of the Qt libraries (pyside2/6, PyQt5/6).

So you can get this error if you have a broken install of Qt. You may want to reinstall PySide6 or whatever you've been using.

You could also use a tool like `strace` and spy on the Python process (if you're using Linux) to see exactly what it's looking for.

```
strace python -c 'from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt'
```

I used this technique to track down why this import was failing under Docker but working properly on a regular desktop.

For the (Ubuntu) Docker container to properly support the import statement, I had to also install these missing libraries:

```
apt install -y libegl1 libgl1 libxkbcommon0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are indeed messing with imports. In detail it seems

```
import PIL.ImageQt as PQ
```

is in conflict with

```
self.currentSeg = PQ.ImageQt(self.currentSeg)
```

If `ImageQt` is the Object you want to access, then I suggest to change the lines as it follows:

```
import PIL.ImageQt as PQ
self.currentSeg = PQ(self.currentSeg)
```